# The exported data frame is text rather than numeric in Excel file

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame and want to export it as an excel file. I can do it but when exporting, the format of each number is text rather than numeric in excel file.

Here is the screenshot of my data frame.

[image]

And I export it as excel using the following code.

```
write.xlsx(as.data.frame(t_outfile),file="t_outfile.xlsx",rowNames = TRUE,colNames = FALSE)
```

The name of my data frame is "t_outfile". But after exporting, the format of each number is text in excel. Here is the screenshot of the exported file.

[image]

Is there anyone helping me export an excel file with the proper format of number?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I find how to fix this problem. Here is the code.

```
t_outfile<-data.matrix(t_outfile,rownames.force = NA)
t_outfile<-as.data.frame(t_outfile)
```

First, I convert the data frame as a numeric matrix and then transform it back to the data frame. After this, the exported results are the numeric format for all numbers.

Comment: This suggests your original types were not numeric as R screenshot shows with left justification. Show output of `str(t_outfile)` before this `data.matrix` call.